# Magento Admin : How to show custom calculation besides admin grid pager in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, grid

In admin, I want to show custom calculations next to pager in custom module's grid.

If there is any a way to do that, please share.

Example : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to change the template of your grid.
By default the grid is rendered with the template [`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml)

You need to add this in your grid block `__construct` method after calling `parent::__construct()`.

```
$this->setTemplate('your_folder/grid.phtml');
```

If the method `__construct` does not exist, create it and make it look like this:

```
public function __construct($attributes=array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->setTemplate('your_folder/grid.phtml'); 
}
```

then copy the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml` to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/your_folder/grid.phtml`

Now you can do modifications in your new file.
You should insert the code that shows your custom values [right after the pager](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml#L90)